# How to make a key generated, 7 segment display, output persist after the key is released? [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I'm trying to read input from the keypad and I want the number entered by the user to persist on a 7 segment display until another key is pressed.

Currently, the 7 segment display output disappears when the key is released. How can I make the 7 segment display output persist?

This is my entire code :

```
ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF keypad IS 

SIGNAL  t1, t2, t3, t4: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 TO 4) := "1111";
SIGNAL curr : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO 4) := "0111";
BEGIN 
proc_1: PROCESS
BEGIN

WAIT UNTIL rising_edge(clk);

        IF curr <= "0111" THEN  t1<= row ;

        curr <= "1011";

        ELSIF curr <= "1011" THEN t2<= row ;

        curr <= "1101";

        ELSIF curr <= "1101" THEN t3<= row ;

        curr <= "1110";

        ELSIF curr <= "1110" THEN t4<= row ;

        curr <= "0111";

        ELSE 
         curr <= "0111";
    END IF ;
END PROCESS ;
    proc_2: PROCESS (t1, t2, t3, t4)
    BEGIN
    hit <= '1';
    IF t1(1) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "1001111" ; --1
    ELSIF t1(2) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "1001100" ;  --4
    ELSIF t1(3) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0001111" ;  --7
    ELSIF t1(4) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "1111111" ;  --*
    ELSIF t2(1) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0010010" ;  --2
    ELSIF t2(2) = '0' THEN sevenseg <="0100100" ;   --5
    ELSIF t2(3) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0000000" ; --8
    ELSIF t2(4) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0000001" ; --0
    ELSIF t3(1) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0000110" ;  --3
    ELSIF t3(2) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0100000" ;  --6
    ELSIF t3(3) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0000100" ;  --9
    ELSIF t3(4) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "1111111" ;  --#
    ELSIF t4(1) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0001000" ;  --A
    ELSIF t4(2) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "1111111" ;  --B
    ELSIF t4(3) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "0110001" ;  --C
    ELSIF t4(4) = '0' THEN sevenseg <= "1111111" ;  --D
    ELSE 
        hit <= '0'; 
    END IF;
    END PROCESS;
    col <= curr ;       
END Behavioral ;
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, so we can read and understand what you've written so far. The solution is a register that stores your information for a time span or infinitly, after releasing the button. Do not initilaize signals, which are not translated to registers in an FPGA. You sensitivity list of the 2nd process is wrong. You need to list all read signals, not the signals you update. The 2nd process created latches for all `t*` signals.

Comment: so you mean that the second process should have a row in the sensitive list?, I don't know where should I use register and for which signal

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the second process. Please ignore my comment for the second process.

Comment: could you please give me a hint on how to use registers?